# HTTPPost does not work asp mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

I am really confused,
here is the code :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Settings(string SubmitButton)
    {
        if (SubmitButton == "Sign In") {
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IAppContext>().LoggedUser = null;
            Response.Cookies["loginuser"].Expires = DateTime.Now;
            return RedirectToAction("Logon", "Account");
        }
        if (SubmitButton == "Sign Up") { return RedirectToAction("register", "Account"); }
        if (SubmitButton == "Change Default Ride Settings") { return RedirectToAction("changeSettings", "Home"); }
        return View();
    }
```

The view contain

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {  %>

   Three input ,

<% } %>
```

the controller is not fired with httppost but fired with httpget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to pass in the controller and action names in Html.BeginForm() in your view.  Since the [HttpPost] Settings() action is being invoked for HTTP get requests, that implies that there isn't another Settings() action for get requests, so I'm guessing that your view is being served from a different action.  In such a case, you need to explicitly set the controller and action in your Html.BeginForm().  Try this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Settings", "YourControllerName")) { %>
```

Comment: No the problem was with jquerymobile ,i fixed it with the version 1.03

Comment: @Khaldoun could you please share ur answer, I am also using JQUeryMobile and struggling with similar problem,in my case RedirectToAction of LogOn Method not working and address bar padded with # sign and redirect address...clueless

Answer (score 2):

You have to generate a html form with the method attribute set to post if you want a post to happen:

```
Html.BeginForm("action","controller", FormMethod.Post) { ... }
```

Comment: That was my first thought too, but [the parameterless BeginForm does default to FormMethod.Post](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/63930#288009).

Answer (score 0):

There should be action with name Index() and should not containg any parameters in it. This is the problem I have faced.

Answer (score 0):

I have used ActionName() to solve the same problem,

Not working code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ViewResult RsvpForm()
    {

    [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult RsvpFrom()
        {
        }
```

Working code:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ViewResult RsvpForm()
        {
        }
        [HttpPost, ActionName("RsvpForm")]
        public ViewResult RsvpFromPost()
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way using razor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
{
   //form content
}
```